# Proper memory management when appending to NSString

Tags: ios, memory, nsstring

I have an `NSString` object that I've allocated. I want to append to this string occasionally throughout the lifetime of the app
I am confused about how to properly handle the memory in the example below. Thanks.

1. Do I need to retain the string that I am appending each time, or is it OK to append with a string that belongs to the autorelease pool, as `stringByAppendingString:` returns?
2. Am I leaking the memory that was previously assigned to `my_string` each time I do an append?

Code:

```
NSString* my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Initial string"];
NSString* something = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @" with something"];
my_string = [[my_string stringByAppendingString:something] retain];
NSString* something_else = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @" and something_else"];
my_string = [[my_string stringByAppendingString:something_else] retain];
[my_string release];
```

Comment: Still managing memory yourself! why don't use ARC in Xcode 4.2!!

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString* my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Initial string"];
```

is not autoreleased (as it is created with an init... method, this is a convention), it has a retainCount of 1.

```
NSString* something = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @" with something"];
```

is autoreleased.

> is it OK to append with a string that belongs to the autorelease pool, as
>   stringByAppendingString: returns

As long as you would expect it to live for yes. However in your code:

```
NSString* my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Initial string"];
NSString* something = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @" with something"];
my_string = [[my_string stringByAppendingString:something] retain];
```

you have a leak. You should autorelease my_string before re-assigning it. So the last line should be:

```
my_string = [[[my_string autorelease] stringByAppendingString:something] retain];
```

otherwise you have forever lost the pointer to the object you are meant to have released. As you retain the result, you are responsible for releasing it so you also have a leak in the line before last which should be

```
my_string = [[[my_string autorelease] stringByAppendingString:something_else] retain];
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense that I first need to autorelease my_string each time that I am doing the append operation. This seems really ugly. Is there no better way to simply append to an existing string without first releasing the old string and retaining the new one that is created? Thanks again.

Comment: `NSMutableString`? The problem is that `NSString`, being immutable, only returns brand new objects that then overwrite the references to the old immutable objects when you assign them to the same variable, causing a leak. `NSMutableString` would let you append to the string in place, no extra assignments necessary.

Comment: You can also not retain them, then you won't have to autorelease them :)

Answer (score 1):

The primary thing to keep in mind is that `NSString` is immutable. Whether you alloc, create with format, or append, you're always getting a *new* string object returned. So let's break this down:

```
NSString* my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Initial string"];
//String object created with "Initial string" content. Retain +1

NSString* something = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @" with something"];
//String object created with content " with something" and autoreleased.

my_string = [[my_string stringByAppendingString:something] retain];
//String object created with content "Initial string with something", autorelesed, and retained. Effective retain +1
//Assignment replaces old "Initial string" reference. "Initial string" object still has retain of +1, so it doesn't get deallocated (it leaks).

NSString* something_else = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @" and something_else"];
//String object created with content " and something_else" and autoreleased.

my_string = [[my_string stringByAppendingString:something_else] retain];
//String object created with contents "Initial string with something and something_else", autoreleaased, and retained. Effective retain +1
//Assignment replaces old "Initial string with something" reference. "initial string with something" object still had a retain of +1, so the object leaks.

[my_string release];
//String object "Initial string with something and something_else" released. Retain -1. Object is deallocated and doesn't leak.

//...Sometime later at the end of the runloop, the autorelease pool is drained and " with something" and " with something_else" are both deallocated.
```

So:

1. Yes. It's ok to append an autoreleased string. `release` is not called on an autoreleased object until the end of the run loop, which, at the very least, is after this method exits.
2. Yes, you are leaking the objects that were previously assigned to `my_string` each time you do an append... but it's not the append that's causing the leak, it's the assignment. You could assign `nil` to `my_string` and the retained object `my_string` used to point to would still leak if you didn't `release` or `autorelease` it first.

Comment: Thanks, so would you agree with jbat100 that this is the best way to append to an existing string:  my_string = [[[my_string autorelease] stringByAppendingString:something] retain];

Comment: My above comment assumes that the my_string must be valid beyond the end of the current run loop. The inital string allocation would not have happened in the same block of code. Would you agree with comment above in that case? Thanks.

Comment: If `my_string` must be valid beyond the end of the runloop (and outside the given method) maybe a property is the correct solution? A synthesized property takes care of all the releasing and retaining for you.

Or maybe `NSMutableString`?
 
Out of habit, I would probably `NSString *oldString = my_string; my_string = [[my_string stringByAppendingString:@"foo"] retain]; [oldString release];` So as not to wait for the autorelease for the old string's RAM to be reclaimed (important on early iPhone models). But either way is fine.

Comment: The retain count won't be 1 after that first line of code.... but that is an implementation detail.  Bottom line;  treating retain count as an absolute value is wrong.

Comment: @bbum Thanks! Very true. In answering a question like this, is there a good way to express "You have X opaque ownership units invested in this object that must be balanced with X `release` or `autorelease` calls" without insinuating a (false) relationship with `-retainCount`? Other than "Use ARC", I mean ;-)

Comment: Yes;  retain counts are always deltas.  I.e. instead of saying "retain count is now 1 (2 or 42)", say "retain count +1" or "retain count -1".

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd assignment you're losing the retained reference of the first `stringByAppendingString` call, so:

1. It's OK to append with a string without calling retain, unless you're needing the value later in the code.
2. Yes, each call to `stringByAppendingString` returns a new autoreleased string. Don't retain it if you're using the value temporarily.